# How to make only the clicked element show the background color through javascript, and the rest of the elements disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make only the clicked element show the background color through javascript, and the rest of the elements disappear?
Since I'm just learning the language, I don't quite know how to fix my code to achieve this effect?

thank you all.

```js
function addStyle() {
  this.style.background = "blue";
}

var el = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', addStyle);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By "disappear" do you mean if they have a blue background they should go back to white, or do you mean the elements should be removed completely from the page?

Comment: @Andy
Sorry I didn't express clearly, disappearing means only the blue of the background disappears, only the background of the clicked element appears blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting the background to blue, unset all of the backgrounds:

```js
function addStyle() {
  // unset all backgrounds
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].style.background = "unset";
  }
  // set this one to blue
  this.style.background = "blue";
}

var el = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', addStyle);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, very clear!
Also let me gain new knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary to David's answer you might also consider using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Instead of attaching multiple listeners to multiple elements add *one* to the containing element (the list) and catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. You can then [check that the element is a list item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), remove all the classes from the other list items, and [set the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for the clicked child element.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const items = list.querySelectorAll('li');

list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('blue'));
    e.target.classList.add('blue');
  }
}
```

```css
.blue { background-color: lightblue; }
li:hover:not(.blue) { cursor: pointer; background-color: #efefef; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```